# Playlists in foobar2000

Tags: music, foobar2000

I am trying my best to get used to foobar2000, but I am still missing one thing. When I play one album by double clicking the first song it automatically plays all the songs of that album. But I don't understand which playlist is now playing. Is there any way I can see the currently playing album in a playlist? It should function like a now playing-queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The playlist in question is what foobar2000 calls the "playback queue". That isn't exposed anywhere in default foobar2000 as far as I know, but [this plugin](http://foosion.foobar2000.org/components/?id=pqview&version=0.2) allows you to specify a playlist which will show the playback queue's contents.

Comment: Thank you, can I somehow change the name of that playlist from "Filter Results (Playback)" to something else? Every time I rename it a new playlist called "Filter Results (Playback)" is created.

Comment: You may be able to change it in the options for the plugin, which should be I think under Preferences -> Components (not at a Windows box at the moment, so can't check, sorry.) If not there, I think you're stuck with "Filter Results (Playback)" unless you want to rebuild the plugin from source.

Comment: Ok, I've already looked everywhere. Thank you!

Comment: Sure! Glad to be of help.